# Stop background image from going behind header/footer

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage that has a header and a footer. The background image goes behind both of them cutting about 1/4th the top of the image off behind the header and another 1/4th off behind the footer. Here is my CSS for my background image.

```
background-image: url('http://codegamer.net/images/majestic/patterns/lol2.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

I just want the image to start under the header and end before the footer so I can see the full image.

Comment: A fiddle will make your question more understandable.

Comment: Here is my fiddle www.codegamer.net

Comment: Not a link...a Jsfiddle.net demo.

Answer (score 1):

1- Remove those properties from the body div.

2- Create a new div that contains the `<div id="container">`, like this:

HTML

```
 <div id="container-background">
   <div id="container">...</div>
 </div>
```

3- Assign the following properties to your new div:

CSS

```
#container-background {
  background-image: url('http://codegamer.net/images/majestic/patterns/lol2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just applied it and still doing the same thing.

Comment: Just checked your page. Try removing `background: #ffffff`from `#container`. It should look like this http://grab.by/zXE4

Comment: To the right of "Creat A Account" Is a font awesome icon. Click it and it will drop down a jQuery box where you can select a different background. Select the very last Background Image. It is a purple one.

Comment: This moves the start of the header down 142px. But when you scroll down the image still stays 142px down so there is whitespace on top. Also, this doesn't make the image stop before the footer. It just pushes everything down so the bottom of the image is now cut off 142px more than what it was originally cut off.